How do I plot wind speed on the Y axis of my R bar chart?
I am trying to make a basic bar graph in R using geom_bar. I am trying to show the maximum windspeeds of famous hurricanes. Here is my code:
storms %>% 
  filter(name %in% c("Igor","Katrina","Sandy")) %>%
  group_by(name) %>% 
  summarize(max_wind_speed=max(wind)) %>% 
  ggplot() +
  geom_bar(aes(x=max_wind_speed,fill=name))

Instead of having windspeed on the y-axis,however, I end up with windspeed on the x axis and a "count" of the hurricanes on the y-axis. I've tried the obvious solution of putting wind speed on the y axis without success.Here is my graph:


Try with geom_col(aes(x=name, y = max_wind_speed,fill=name))
